# Fuzzy Match Algorithm for Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, fuzzy-search

I am working on an app that uses OCR to grab text from an image and searches the text in a MYSQL database of ~10,000 records. Most of the time the text scanned from image is not accurate (missing or mispelled words) so I am using Fuse to do the fuzzy matching... it works well against a small lists but it is very slow running - it takes 5 mins to scan thru 10K records, and is not that accurate (about 50% match rate).

Can anyone recommend a library or method of taking mispelled or mis-ordered text from an OCR scan and matching it to the correct database record?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Setting variables
private var allBooks = [Book]()
let fuse = Fuse()
var bookNames = [String]()

var OCRArray : [String] = []

// Get all books from database
    sqlConfig.configureMySQL()
    BooksProvider().loadBooks { books in
        self.allBooks = books
    }

// Put list of books in string array in order for fuse search to work
    for object in allBooks {
        let strName = object.name ?? ""
        bookNames.append(strName)
    }

// Function that iterates thru each line of OCR scan that is stored in OCRArray
// This takes several 5+ to complete
func fuseMatch() {
    for x in 0..<OCRArray.count {

        var results = fuse.search(OCRArray[x], in: bookNames)

        var fuseWine:String

        if results.first != nil {
            fuseMatch = bookNames[results[0].index]

        } else {
            fuseMatch = "Not found."
        }
        print(x, " | ", OCRArray[x], " | ", fuseMatch)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want the matching to happen locally? I'm seeing that you pulled 10,000 books from your DB just to get the titles?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can use fuse directly to fuzzy match a database query, it requires a string array to match... which I'm downloading and putting into string array.

Comment: Sorry just trying to understand your code better. What’s in the OCRArray? Is it an array of words or book titles?

Comment: It is an array of book titles scanned via ocr... So I take a picture of a list of book titles and it stores each line in an array